# Moving Old Server's System Drive to a New Server

Tags: hard-drive, drivers, windows-server-2012

I need to know whether it's possible to move the system drive from an older server computer to a new server computer with completely different parts and specs without having to reinstall Windows or lose any programs or data.

If so, how would I go about doing this? I'm guessing new drivers would have to be installed, but how do I do this? Will i still be able to boot into windows server if incorrect drivers are currently installed? The OS is Windows Server 2012. Will the system automatically boot into a mode where it installs the necessary drivers automatically like it does in Windows 10 when you change the system parts? I can't remember if it did this or not on earlier versions of windows.

I can't find any great info online about doing this "dirty" transfer from server to server without having to install Windows from scratch on a new drive and then using a Windows shadow copy of the old drive to install on the new drive. I just want to transfer the entire drive over, nothing extra.

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't Linux. Windows licensing will get in the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even Servers come with OEM licensing and you cannot move an OEM license. Then even if you tried, it almost for sure will not boot because of drivers. No , drivers will not automatically update

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer :) How would I manually update the drivers then? Could i install the drivers on the old server and that way once it's transferred over to the other server it will already have those drivers? We have a Windows server 2012 license key that we can use to reactivate it on the new server PC.

Comment: You can try that, but you need a retail license of Server 2012 to do that.